# what is qdb? database

Tags: database, database-design

At my work place they use qdb to store data. Can someone tell me in more detail "why qdb?" and can you refer me to some link so that I can read more about it? because everytime i search for qdb i find GDB pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not ask people at work who actually use it? :)

Third link on google explains what it is:

> ```
> QDB database
> QDB is a user-contributed database that can read and write DBASE files.
> filburt.lns.mit.edu/oops/Html/SW/wxwin/wx/wx15.htm
> ```

EDIT: The most productive Google search so far is:

> ```
> qdb database -quotes -gdb
> ```

Comment: +1, __Why not ask people at work who actually use it?__

Comment: Fear of looking stupid and incompetent, I have had a fair few colleagues who would ask the faceless internet first.

Comment: As I usually tell newbies at work (and elsewhere), "The only stupid question is one you did not ask me but should have"

Comment: @whatnick, oh crap, I must be completely stupid and incompetent! I ask lots of questions!!